# How to draw border below the text using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am using Bootstrap.I have placed the text in the middle but unable to make this border which is thick in middle below the text.

[image: How to draw border which is thick in the middle as shown in this image using CSS]

Comment: Please post your html and css so we can examine the problem.

Comment: what have you done so far ? post your code

Answer (score 2):

**Try This:**

```css
span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

span:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<span>National Programming</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [linear-gradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) for this. No pseudo elements needed :)

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background:linear-gradient(to right, transparent 5%, 
    #ccc 5%, #ccc 40%, 
    #111 40%, #111 55%, 
    #ccc 55%, #ccc 95%, 
    transparent 95% ) bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>National Programming</div>
```

**NB:** In the OP's illustration, the bottom border doesn't quite reach the edges of the text - because of this I have added transparent color on both sides of the linear gradient